# Integral involving trig exponentiation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I came across this integral online

> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{x^3 \sin x}{1+e^{x \cos x}} dx$$

But every approach I've tried so far doesn't get me anywhere. I tried substituting $u=\cos x$, which doesn't really change much. Following that, I tried to separate the integrand with varying powers of $x$ in order to attempt an integration by parts, to no avail.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note the symmetry of the bounds: we can pull a trick here by splitting up the bounds into $(-\pi, 0)$ and $(0, \pi)$ and use $u = -x$ on the negative half to get some interesting cancelling. The resulting integral is fairly elementary.

Comment: I feel like I should've noticed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know, $$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
So $$I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{x ^3\sin x}{1+e^{x\cos x}}dx= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{x ^3\sin x}{1+e^{-x\cos x}}dx $$$$\implies I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{x\cos x}x ^3\sin x}{1+e^{x\cos x}}dx$$ Adding both the expressions, we get
$$2I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^3\sin xdx=2\int_0^\pi x^3\sin xdx$$ (the integrand is even) so that $$I=\int_0^\pi x^3\sin xdx$$ and I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Lemma that generalizes @insipidintegrator's answer, which I think is a nice tool to have when evaluating integrals:

> Given $E(x), \mathcal{E}(x)$ [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions) functions, $O(x)$ an [odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions) function and $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{\infty\}$, $$ \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x= \int_0^{a} E(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
>  $$
> if the integrals are well defined.

***Proof:*** Since $E(-x) =E(x)$, $\mathcal{E}(-x) =\mathcal{E}(x) $ and $O(-x) = -O(x)$, denoting the integral as $I=\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}$ we can take the substitution $x \to -x$ and get
$$
I=\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x \overset{\color{darkblue}{x\to -x}}{=}-\int_{a}^{-a} \frac{E(-x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(-x)^{O(-x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x= \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{-O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
$\require{\cancel}$
where we used that $-\int_A^B f = \int_B^A f$ t change the limits of integration. Thus
\begin{align}
2I &= \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x  + \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{-O(x)}} \frac{\color{purple}{\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}}{\color{purple}{\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x  + \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{\color{purple}{\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& =  \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}+ \frac{\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}E(x)}{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
& =  \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{E(x)\left(\cancel{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}} \right)}{\cancel{1+\mathcal{E}(x)^{O(x)}}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
But again recalling that $E(x) = E(-x)$ because it's even, we get
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{-a}^{0} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right)\\
&\overset{\color{darkblue}{x\to -x}}{=}\frac{1}{2} \left(\color{darkblue}{-}\int_{a}^{0} E(\color{darkblue}{-x})\,\mathrm{d}\color{darkblue}{x} + \int_{0}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{0}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{\cancel{2}}\left(\cancel{2}\int_{0}^{a} E(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right)
\end{align}
Q.E.D.

---

Applying the Lemma to your integral we immediately get
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{1+e^{x\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^\pi x^3 \sin(x)\mathrm{d}x \\
&\overset{\text{I.B.P.}}{=}-x^3\cos(x)+3x^2\sin(x)+6x\cos(x)-6\sin(x)\Bigg\vert_{0}^{\pi}\\
& = \pi^3-6\pi = \boxed{\pi(\pi^2-6)}
\end{align}
as shown in @insipidintegrator's answer. But there are all sorts of crazy-looking integrals that can be evaluated using this same Lemma/technique, for example

- $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^{2022x})} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} =\frac{\pi}{2} $$
- $$ \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{sech}^2(x) + \cosh(x)^{\sinh(x) -2}} = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \cosh^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{8}\left(e - e^{-1} +2 \right)$$
- $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+ |x|^{\mathrm{erf}(\sin(x))}}\,\mathrm{d}x =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: Love this answer! Btw, in the first integral, is it okay to use it for improper integrals?

Comment: This is a brilliant one. Just to be sure, in the case of $a=\infty$ I would add "if the integrals are well defined, then.."

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've added the note that @Gabrielek suggested.